# Massive color temperature shifts with GNOME Night Light when selecting text

Tags: drivers, gnome, xorg, display, redshift

GNOME night light works fine with color temperatures ~>4500. Once I start dipping below 4500 I get the behavior shown in the gif below. I issue the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-temperature 2500
```

and my screen looks fine. Then if I take an innocuous action, like highlight some text, the color temperature changes from my requested `2500` up to something like `5500`. Then as I deselect the text the color temperature moves back down to `2500`.

Why is my computer doing this? The color temperature randomly jumping all over the map is not preferred behavior.

Sorry for the lousy recording. For some strange reason, if I record this happening with *Peek* or *SimpleScreenRecorder* it won't properly capture what is happening. It will capture the behavior if I playback at a low color temperature (eg 3500). But if I playback the *Peek* gif at normal color temperature (eg 6500) the behavior disappears in the video. Probably a clue to the issue, although it doesn't help me troubleshoot.

**Is this a GNOME night light issue? Video driver? Kernel? Monitor?** Selecting or deselecting text shouldn't cause the screen color temperature to change.

[image]

Comment: Try `sct 2000`? If the same thing happens it's not something unique to GNOME Night light. I don't see the odd effect you're seeing when I use `sct 2000`.

Comment: @DK Bose I was hopeful your suggestion from last week to use `sct 2000` would solve the issue. But it occurs with `sct ____` as well. What does that tell us?

Comment: I have just one laptop with Intel integrated graphics and so can't add more to the issue.